# How is Underscrore's now method is faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, date, time, underscore.js

I am curious how Underscore's `_.now` method is faster than just `new Date().getTime()`.
I see the following on their github codebase.

```
// A (possibly faster) way to get the current timestamp as an integer.
_.now = Date.now || function() {
    return new Date().getTime();
};
```

Can someone please explain what's going on here ?

Comment: With arrow functions you get `_.now = Date.now || () => +new Date()`. ;-) But I guess anything that doesn't support *Date.now* isn't going to support arrow functions…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it doesn't have to construct a `new Date` object, using the advantage provided by `Date.now`. The only problem with that was that browser support, so they included a fallback. It might as well have been a better idea to simply include a polyfill

```
if (typeof Date.now != "function")
  Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); };
```

and use that instead of advocating their own helper function.

Comment: Libraries like underscore, lodash, jQuery don't make changes to the regular JS environment, they provide all their functions in their own namespace.

Comment: Like `$.each()` instead of an `Array.prototype.forEach` polyfill.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that approach has several obvious advantages. I just would love to see it used only for their core functionality which provides *more* than the standard methods, and keep their compatibility layer internal instead of exposing on the namespace (unless that's the explicit library purpose, of course).

Comment: @Barmar Well `$.each` does in no way come even close to a `forEach` polyfill :-)

Comment: OK, maybe `$.inArray()` is a better example.

Answer (score 0):

By using Date.now, you don't need to construct an Object. But it is not supported in IE < 9. In this case, it use the old new Date().getTime function.

[image: Comparison]

You can refer this link for detail of browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=Date.now